# Difference between PlotModel.InvalidatePlot() and PlotView.InvalidatePlot()

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I've come across this page in the Oxyplot documentation:

https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/master/common-tasks/refresh-plot.html

However there is no obvious explanation of what the difference is between calling InvalidatePlot() on the PlotModel as opposed to the PlotView

In addition the application I'm working on stores a number of entities each of which represents an experiment and associated result data. Each one stores a PlotModel that's supposed to be assigned to the PlotView when that entity is selected in the UI.

I have one model assigned to the PlotView in the View and this model exists as a public property in the associated view model. This property is supposed to represent the PlotModel within the selected entity, but trying to modify this property from within the code when changing from one entity to another results in the 'This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control.' error occurring when it gets to the line in the property setter that calls NotifyOfPropertyChanged().

Does anybody know how to work around this? Are the InvalidatePlot() calls above something I ought to be looking into or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a difference between calling Invalidate on the PlotModel or the PlotView. Calling it on the PlotModel only calls the the same-named method on the view. See here: [https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/PlotModel/PlotModel.cs#L522](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/PlotModel/PlotModel.cs#L522)

Comment: Does this exception occur immediately or does it show up if you select a previously selected entity a second time? In the latter case, it might be necessary to detach the view from the entity's PlotModel when it gets unselected by calling 'AttachPlotView(null)' on it. This exception is thrown if you bind the PlotModel to a PlotView although it is already bound to a view. This is even the case if the new view is the very same instance as the first one.